# Open neighborhoods in a topological subspace

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a topological space $X$, an element $x\in X$, and an open neighborhood $x \in O \subset X$. Further, suppose that $X$ is a topological subspace of $Y$.

I am trying to figure out under what conditions there must exist an open neighborhood of $x$ in $Y$?

Comment: $Y$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. Are you sure you're phrasing the question right?

Comment: Maybe you want $O=U\cap X$ for some $U\subset Y$ open? But that is just the definition of subset topology

Comment: Induced topology

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the question as written is trivial since $Y$ is open.

The requirement $O = U \cap X$ for some $U \subset Y$ open is also true by definition of relative topology.

Thanks.